# Dapr Actor Runtime Configuration Issue

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dapr

I attempted to deploy my project using Docker Compose to test the Dapr Actor API, but I encountered an issue. The logs of container app1 provide the following error message:

```
2023-10-01 14:07:18 Unhandled exception. Dapr.DaprApiException: the state store is not configured to use the actor runtime. Have you set the - name: actorStateStore value: "true" in your state store component file?
2023-10-01 14:07:18    at Dapr.Actors.DaprHttpInteractor.SendAsyncHandleUnsuccessfulResponse(Func`1 requestFunc, String relativeUri, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2023-10-01 14:07:18    at Dapr.Actors.DaprHttpInteractor.SendAsync(Func`1 requestFunc, String relativeUri, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2023-10-01 14:07:18    at Dapr.Actors.DaprHttpInteractor.InvokeActorMethodWithRemotingAsync(ActorMessageSerializersManager serializersManager, IActorRequestMessage remotingRequestRequestMessage, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2023-10-01 14:07:18    at Dapr.Actors.Communication.Client.ActorRemotingClient.InvokeAsync(IActorRequestMessage remotingRequestMessage, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2023-10-01 14:07:18    at Dapr.Actors.Client.ActorProxy.InvokeMethodAsync(Int32 interfaceId, Int32 methodId, String methodName, IActorRequestMessageBody requestMsgBodyValue, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2023-10-01 14:07:18    at Dapr.Actors.Client.ActorProxy.ContinueWithResult[TRetval](Int32 interfaceId, Int32 methodId, Task`1 task)
2023-10-01 14:07:18    at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in /src/App1/Program.cs:line 12
2023-10-01 14:07:18    at Program.<Main>(String[] args)
```

The log is indicating that I haven't set **`actorStateStore`** to **`true`**, but in reality, I've already configured it in the **`statestore.yaml`** file.

statestore.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: dapr.io/v1alpha1
kind: Component
metadata:
  name: statestore
spec:
  type: state.redis
  version: v1
  metadata:
  - name: redisHost
    value: redis:6379
  - name: redisPassword
    value: ""
  - name: actorStateStore
    value: "true"
```

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
# Please refer https://aka.ms/HTTPSinContainer on how to setup an https developer certificate for your ASP.NET Core service.

version: '3.4'

services:
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    ports:
      - "6380:6379"
    networks:
      - test-net
      
  placement:
    image: "daprio/dapr"
    command: ["./placement", "-port", "50006"]
    ports:
      - "50006:50006"
    networks:
      - test-net

  app1:
    image: app1
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: App1/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 5001:5001
    depends_on:
      - app2
      - redis
      - placement
    networks:
      - test-net

  app1-dapr:
    image: "daprio/daprd:edge"
    command: [ "./daprd", 
      "-app-id", "app1", 
      "-app-port", "5001",
      "-components-path", "/components",
      "-placement-host-address", "placement:50006"
      ]
    volumes:
      - "./dapr/components/:/components"
    network_mode: "service:app1"
    depends_on:
      - app1

  app2:
    image: app2
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: App2/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 5002:5002
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - placement
    networks:
      - test-net

  app2-dapr:
    image: "daprio/daprd:edge"
    command: [ "./daprd", 
      "-app-id", "app2", 
      "-app-port", "5002",
      "-components-path", "/components",
      "-placement-host-address", "placement:50006"
      ]
    volumes:
      - "./dapr/components/:/components"
    network_mode: "service:app2"
    depends_on:
      - app2

networks:
  test-net:
```

Comment: Are you specifying the correct statestore for your Actors? eg. "statestore"